# Retrieving data from database without freezing the UI Winforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, async-await

What i want to do is... retrieving data from database without freezing the UI during adding thousands of data into it.

I was already read about async/await method, but i think i got wrong to implement the async/await method, cause the UI was still freezing

Could you please tell me where i was got wrong and including the example of correct method as well?

Thank you very much

```
public async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    await loadingMsn(sourceMsn);
}

public static async Task loadingMsn(AutoCompleteStringCollection srcData)
{

    try
    {
        string queryMsn =
            "SELECT " +
                "MsnNo, " +
                "Carline, " +
                "Prod, " +
                "MsnSeries, " +
                "Area " +
            "FROM " +
                "ms_MsnInspect";
        SqlConnection con;
        con = Koneksi.Conn;
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryMsn, con);
        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        SqlDataReader Sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (Sdr.Read())
            {
                srcData.Add(Sdr["MsnNo"].ToString());
            }
        
        Sdr.Close();
        con.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: You want to use the async versions of `ExecuteReader` and `Read`. It's blocking while looping over the results.

Comment: don't use the await.

Comment: Ahh i see, could you guys tell me what i have to use rather than async/await ? @LévayLőrinc

Comment: You can also look at the [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-7.0) class, which can work on a separate thread, This won't freeze your ui.

Comment: Thanks guys, BackgroundWorker method solved my problem

Comment: @lhmrnfrzrfr I have made an answer with it, you could mark it as the answer which could help the person has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment, the solution is to use [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-7.0) class,which can work on a separate thread.

This won't freeze your ui.